# Compiling inno .iss file with the command line

Tags: command-line, inno-setup, exe

I am trying to turn an Inno .iss file to the installer .exe over the command line.

I have found this page on the Inno website which shows you how to do this:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline

When I tried these commands, I got the command not found error:

```
'compil32' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I got the same error when trying iscc instead of compil32. I also tried compil64, as my computer is 64 bit, with the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basic operating system functionality. You need to either put the directories where the Inno Setup binaries are located into your system `PATH`, or use a fully qualified pathname to the executables when running them.